# OpenCV Matrix multiplication transpose

Tags: opencv, matrix, multiplication

normally if you multiply a `1xn` matrix with a `nx1` matrix, you get one number as a result. When I do this in OpenCV by doing `A*B`, I get an `nxn` matrix?

Comment: what are cols and rows of those matrices? what was the result of B*A?

Comment: A has 390 rows and 1 column whereas B has 1 row and 390 columns. But the result of B*A is 1x1 matrix, which is good :) But why dies A*B return a 390x 390 matrix?

Comment: i remember that opencv Mat constructor has a reversed order of rows/cols and width/height. you need to check the docs and see

Comment: A 390x1 vector times a 1x390 vector is a 390x390 matrix, that's just matrix multiplication basics ... Matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: As seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics) a matrix mxn, m is the height and n is the width. When multiplying two matrices m1xn1 with m2xn2, the resulting size is m1xn2 and n1 has to equal m2.